# Defer execution of a method in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I have a controller that takes a message and posts the data to a 3rd party url:

```
def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])

    if @message.valid?
      post_to_server(@message)
    end
end


private 

def post_to_server
 # Http Post to 3rd Party Url
end
```

Message is not a ActiveRecord object. It is a plain ruby object with some ActiveModel validations.

Now my concern here is that my application may appear slow if it is waiting for a response from the 3rd party server. What would be the best way to defer execution of this method so that the user can get a response immediately and the post_to_server part is run in the background?

I've googled a bit and found this: https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

But that requires that my object be an active record object and persisted. This seems a bit overkill for what I need.

Are there any other ways to defer execution of a method until after a response is returned?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is only one simple way to do that and it is to use delayedjob or resque or any other gems that provide delayed background processing. Sending request is IO blocking, so if u send this request if deffered thread, u block the current process in ruby mri.

DelayedJob will marshal your object using YAML and then convert it back for the execution, so u can pass any object.

```
class Message
  def post_to_server
    # long running method
  end
  handle_asynchronously :post_to_server
end
```

`@message.post_to_server`
or

```
class Jobs
  def self.post_to_server(message)
    # long running method
  end
  handle_asynchronously :post_to_server
end
```

`Jobs.post_to_server(@message)`

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job

Comment: I tried self.delay.post_to_server and got an error: can't dump anonymous module: #<Module:0x175eb28c>

Answer (score 2):

I don't think delayed_job cares so much about ActiveRecord objects or persistence.  As mentioned in the documentation:

*Call .delay.method(params) on any object and it will be processed in the background.*

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job#queuing-jobs

We use it as such in our projects with good results.  From my research, delayed_job is the simplest way of achieving what you are after.  There are other queueing mechanisms (RabbitMQ, ZeroMQ) out there that will also help but in my opinion, these are going to be overkill.

In your case try something like:

```
@message.delay.post_to_server
```